# What does "Blast" mean?

Tags: american-english, meaning

I'm having trouble understanding this word's meaning. On Google Translate, it means *explosion* or something like that.

But when I see that word in a sentence, there's no relation, at least for me at my current knowledge.

For example, what does this sentence say?

> In August, Java was blasted as an unsafe plug-in that should only be used...

(Source: http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2012/10/19/apple-kicks-java-out-browsers-in-os-x-update/)

Comment: "To criticize or reprimand severely; to verbally discipline or punish" http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blast#Verb

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *[blast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blast)* is a verb meaning:

> 1. To criticize or attack vigorously.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about this website. Thanks, It will help me a lot. Thanks again!!